# Springboot - validate @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Question: It is possible to validate the JSON payload of a request body, without specifically writing if statements? Maybe via annotation or configuration?

I have a very easy POJO:

```
public class Foo {

    private int important;
    private String something;

//constructors, getter, seters, toString
}
```

And a very easy controller class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionController.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/question")
    Mono<String> question(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        System.out.println("The object foo, with value for important = " + foo.getImportant() + " and something = " + foo.getSomething());
        return Mono.just("question");
    }

}
```

If I query with a payload such as:

```
{
    "important": 42,
    "something": "value"
}
```

Everything is working perfectly fine, very happy.

However, if there is a typo: (note the typo on "important")

```
{
    "importantWithTypo": 42,
    "something": "value"
}
```

Or the required "important" is absent (note the JSON is not even complete)

```
{
    "something": "value"
}
```

The request and computation are still valid! And the value of "important" is 0!

I do not want Spring to default to 0 and to thinks everything is fine.

I also do not want to change my types from primitives to boxed object.

Without me writing something like:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/question")
    Mono<String> question(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        if (0 == foo.getImportant()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        System.out.println("The object foo, with value for important = " + foo.getImportant() + " and something = " + foo.getSomething());
        return Mono.just("question");
    }
```

What is the most efficient way to resolve this? Some kind of annotation? Or maybe Spring boot configuration?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you are using primitive that's why you are getting 0. You can use Integer then you will get null when you don't send the node. And you can use @NotNull to validate the field. And use `@Valid` on `@RequestBody` A good article about validation [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to achieve the same keeping the type int, not Integer?

Comment: Yes you can use `@Min(1)` and use `@Valid` on `@RequestBody`. Read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) for details

Comment: https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add @NotNull annotation on a field (you may need to change type to Integer), and add @Valid annotation on the method parameter of the controller.

```
Mono<String> question(@Valid @RequestBody Foo foo) {
    ...
}
```

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    private Integer important;
    private String something;

//constructors, getter, seters, toString
}
```

You can find more information here: https://lmonkiewicz.medium.com/the-power-of-spring-rest-api-validation-77be83edef

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to achieve the same keeping the type int, not Integer? (upvote for the post)

Comment: You may configure Jackson in such a way, that it will throw DeserializationException when it will try to deserialize `null` (missing field) into `int` using `DeserializationFeature`: `FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES`
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html

Comment: @ŁukaszMonkiewicz Link is broken

Comment: @RBz Try this: https://lmonkiewicz.medium.com/the-power-of-spring-rest-api-validation-77be83edef

Comment: You also need to add these as dependency to use `@Valid` , `@NotNull` etc .                                                      `<dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>`

Comment: Just wanted to say that thanks for reminding me that @Valid does not work on primitives. I expect at least 1 hour wondering my validation wasn't working. In my defense, I stopped coding Java/SpringBoot for about 4 years

Answer (score 7):

The already provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517618/6785908) addresses the question.

However I would like to elaborate on one thing that you asked.

How to fail on this
`"importantWithTypo": 42,`

2 aspects to it.

1. you want to return a 4XX if a required field is not present (this can be achieved by the already given answer) -- `@NonNull`/`@NonEmpty` in conjunction with `@Validate` annotation
2. You want to error out on presence of an unknown field `importantWithTypo`. This can be achieved by jackson's `fail_on_unknown_properties` property. (May be default is `fail_on_unknown_properties = enabled`, I haven't checked so not sure).

**Don't** do this 2nd thing. This will make your 2 services tightly coupled. By doing this `fail_on_unknown_properties = enabled`, you are forfeiting the opportunity to enhance the consumer/caller service in a nonbreaking manner. Then, if you are introducing a new attribute in the entity, you will have to coordinate both the apps releases in such a manner that consumer release will be held until producer/provider makes it. Same goes for rollback, this time in reverse order.